# How can I use ViewBinding with RecyclerView Adapter with an already existing inner class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding

**TodoAdapter.kt**

```
class TodoAdapter (var todos:List<Todo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>(){

  inner class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {

      val view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.todo_layout, parent, false)
      return TodoViewHolder(view)

  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
      holder.itemView.apply {
      }

  }

  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
      return todos.size
  }
}
```

Above is the Recycler View Adapter Class.

I already have an inner class TodoAdapter. How do I use ViewBinding with this?

The layout file from where I want to access views is todo_layout.xml

Comment: Make sure the outermost view of todo_layout is <layout>. 
Then do TodoLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.todo_layout, parent, false); in onCreateViewHolder

Comment: Here is the xml file. https://del.dog/todo_layout.txt

Comment: Here is the new kotlin file as you said https://del.dog/TodoAdapter.go

Comment: Still this is not working.

Comment: Can you tell exactly what is not working? I posted an answer

Comment: DataBindingUtil and getRoot() are shown as error

Comment: @SarahKhan I have added link to the image as an answer what exactly it is showing in android studio. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67765935/14991656

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are familiar with ViewBinding. Here is how you can use ViewBinding with your RecyclerViewAdapter.

Here will be your `TodoAdapter.kt`

```
class TodoAdapter (var todos:List<Todo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        val binding = TodoLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return TodoViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }

    inner class TodoViewHolder(private val binding: TodoLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(){
            binding.apply{
                // Assign Values
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now inside your `TodoViewHolder` bind function call, you can access all your views.

Answer (score 0):

[It shows like this. DataBindingUtil and getRoot() are shown in red. When I hover over it android studio asks me to create class,enum,interface,etc and for getRoot() it shows to create reference and create an extension function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9SG6.png)

[Primary Constructor Call Expected Error on super(binding.root)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ8Kn.png)

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please make sure to remove the last two lines in your onCreateViewHolder. Also there seems to be one extra bracket after getRoot()